# Zabbix: ZBX don't turn into green

Tags: zabbix

ZBX: "Get value from agent failed: TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to [[0.0.0.0]:10050]:connection closed by peer" Please help how to solve this problem? I have used PSK encryption.

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` doesn't look like valid IP address for your host. Set valid IP/DNS name in your host configuration. Or do you want to monitor your localhost agent?

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for your response. My hosts are behind the firewall and NAT. So, I am not sure how to put multiple hosts addresses (private IP addresses) that are behind the NAT. Please suggest.

Comment: Then you need to use active item (agent pushes data into server), not passive items (server pulls data from the agent). Another option is to build Zabbix proxy per private network. See Zabbix doc.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I have been using Active Check items but I am not sure why I am getting that error message. I tried deleting and recreating the hosts but ZBX would turn green for a moment and changes into red giving the error message. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
ZBX doesn't become green in color even after configure templates to the hosts. But once I have enabled the graph (It start polling for the values) or create a graph it becomes green. 
**So the issue is polling or connecting from server to client. Check your configuration in zabbix UI and zabbix-agent.conf file.**

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually, my issue was resolved long time ago after I changed Agent encryption configuration in host configuration page from [PSK][NONE][PSK][CERT] to [NONE][NONE][PSK][CERT]. Since I was monitoring hosts in different locations using active agent, I did not realize that I should not turn on double encryption. Thanks again.